# How Do You Go About Justifying The Same Angle Value For These 2 Triangles

Tags: triangles, angle

In the image I attached below, I am given that the angle theta is in both triangle 1 and triangle 2. I end up trying to rotate triangle 1 to look like triangle 2 and then justify that the location of the angle means the angle is the same for both triangles. Is there a better explanation to compare the angles of two different triangles than this?

[image]

Comment: The radial vector and tangent vector meet at a right angle

Comment: That answered my question. Thank you!!